# Working on a Windows batch job and getting errors on variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here is my code:

```
@echo on
setlocal 
Rem *
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set d=%%i%%j%%k
echo %d% " Starting" > D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\Bills2IC.log
Dir D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\*.zip >> Bills2IC.log
for %%f in (D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\*.zip) do set N=%%~nxf
if exists D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\%N% (    
  echo %N% >> D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\Bills2IC.log
  rename %N% coc_ub_%d%.zip
)
fi
echo %d% " Completed" >> D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\Bills2IC.log
endlocal
```

when I run this code i get this:

```
send_bill2ic.bat
Rem * JCN 10/25/2018 - Batch file for SFTP to Invoice Cloud
Rem *
setlocal
Rem *
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %i in ('date/t') do set d=%i%j%k
set d=11272018
echo 11272018 " Starting"  1>D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\Bills2IC.log
Dir D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\*.zip  1>>Bills2IC.log
for %f in (D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\*.zip) do set N=%~nxf
set N=COC_UBIC_1126.zip
D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\COC_UBIC_1126.zip was unexpected at this time.
if exists D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\COC_UBIC_1126.zip (
```

Thanks in advance for your help
John

Comment: `if exist ...`, not `if exists`. Also there is no `fi` in batch. And you forgot the path to the outputfile in one line.

Comment: Thanks on the exist comment ... the issue is that the variable d seems to work throughout the script but the variable N does not ... i was asking how to ensure that N was filled with the filename that i want to process ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments ... i appreciate the help ... the real error i was looking at was: D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\COC_UBIC_1126.zip was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your syntax. Please check the following piece of code:

```bat
@echo on
setlocal 
Rem *
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set "d=%%i%%j%%k"
echo %d% " Starting" > D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\Bills2IC.log
dir D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\*.zip >> Bills2IC.log
set "N="
for %%I in (D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\*.zip) do set "N=%%~nxI"
  echo %N% >> D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\Bills2IC.log
  rename %N% coc_ub_%d%.zip
echo %d% " Completed" >> D:\Stratus\WaterSewer\Bills2IC.log
endlocal
```

Hope this helps!

Please notify me if you are getting something wrong as I am have done errors due to testing local locations.